# python list iteration

Tags: python, list, iteration

I have a list iteration in python defined like this:

```
for i in range(5):
    for j in range(5):
        if i != j:
            print i , j
```

So for each element in my defined range [0..5] I want to get each element i, but also all other elements which are not i.

This code does exactly as I expect, but is there a cleaner way of doing this?

Comment: You could use range() only once before the two loops as a first level optimization

Comment: From an efficiency point of view, this is perfectly serviceable, unless you're calling it in a tight loop or significantly increasing `5`, I wouldn't worry. From a legibility point of view, this is perfectly readable.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [`itertools.permutations`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations):

```
import itertools as it
for i, j in it.permutations(range(5), 2):
    print i, j
```

Comment: However, the OP's code is very easy to understand without requiring the reader to know itertools; itertools shines when you need to scale these to more dimensions or need it more than once.

Answer (score 2):

[(x,y)for x in range(5) for y in range(5) if x!=y]

Comment: Please provide more information in your answers.  Some background or explanations for posterity is recommended.